# how to place non floating div and floating divs on same line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Currently the list item # appears on the right. If you remove the float from the document-export-icon class, the list item # appears correctly on the left but the title and date are moved to the next line. I need them to be on the same line as the export icon.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/owanod/2/edit#source

Here's how it should look:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the final result should look like? An image, or whatever.

Comment: For starters, you're using `divs` which are block elements. Either use `spans` or specify `display: inline;` on the `divs`. But, as @thirtydot said, an image of the final result would be useful.

Comment: @thirtydot I have uploaded an image of how the final result should look like.

Comment: Are you able to edit the HTML or only the CSS?

Comment: @j08691 I could edit the HTML but for now I would rather edit just the CSS, if possible

Comment: Too many nested divs hurt my eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added these three CSS rules to your example:

```css
.document-export-icon, .document-title-separate, .document-date {
    display: inline-block;
}
.document-date {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
.document-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ma8Lb/1/)**.

Comment: Thanks @j08691, It works fine in FF, Chrome and IE7. In IE 8, the list item # still shows up on the right.

Comment: IE8 isn't an online block fan. Personally I'd prefer to change your HTML rather than shoehorn it via CSS.